# How can I limit the numbers of column in Matrix

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

Unlike Tablix, I was not able to use limiting expression such as `=ceiling(rownumber(nothing)/6)` in Matrix.

Do you have any ideas to achieve limiting no. of columns in matrix- in design only, without touching dataset.

Or I should create it in Tablix?
Any suggestions please?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you could achieve this would be to specify the column and row that you want your data to appear in from within your source dataset.

This could be achieved by taking a `row_number` and then doing integer division (`<row_number value>/6`) to get the row it should fall into and then modular division (`<row_number value>%6`) to get the column it should fall into.

From here you can build up your tablix grouping on your row and column fields.

Comment: ..yes, I got the first part done by having custom code and **ordered by my dataset** . I did the details by following this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c2b89862-b97f-4496-94bc-a5d1fe26580e/how-to-limit-the-columns-per-page-in-ssrs-matrix-report   But for the second part, I don't get it right. Can you please show me in more details?

Comment: I could do it for adding blank rows regardless of data having or not, just by using the modulus function as you have suggested. (lets say) What if I want to have two set of matrixes (one underneath another) although there is only data for 3 columns?

Comment: Hi, Is there alternate way without having row_number to the data? I want to have blank columns at the same time I can't add the row_number too. ? Writing Custom Code?

Comment: @4stars  Why are you writing custom code?  This can all be done in the SQL that populates your dataset.  `row_number()` is an SQL Function.

Comment: hi, I am using sql function, then how can I use it that Row-Number? Sorry it is quite urgent.

Comment: @4stars  You follow the steps in my answer.  Take that row_number and - in your SQL dataset script - divide it by 6 to get the row number and mod it by 6 to get the column.  Also it is against the rules here to push people along because your problem is 'urgent'.  Remember that we are helping you for free.

Comment: I have set the row_number, after that how can I go on? Kindly teach me....

Comment: I am really very sorry.

Comment: `select row_number() over (order by CetegoryID)/6 as RowNum, row_number() over (order by CetegoryID)%6 as ColNum`

Comment: I need to have totals which is grouping by category name (in total ). How can I make use of it in my matrix ?

Comment: @4stars  Do all your aggregation in your SQL query.  It is much more efficient that way.  It is also impossible to have those totals calculated by SSRS if you are not letting it organise the columns as you require.

Comment: hi iamdave, it is exactly like that I have table displaying categories above the matrix. Right now I am having only two datasets, I am getting data from dataset no.2 from second matrix. If I do the aggregate functions inside the sql, i can't display data lines in Tablix. Is there any way out???

Comment: @4stars  Your picture that you linked there adds nothing to your question.  You can use the `partition` part of the `row_number` function to specify the aggregate groupings without actually grouping your individual data rows.  Actually do some research into how these functions work yourself, rather than relying on people such as myself to write your entire solution for you.